# shared variable between instances of program

Tags: c, process, operating-system, execv

I want to share a variable between instances of the same program.

In more detail I have, say 2 processes say p1 and p2 such that: both of them execute some c program, say **prog**, using the execv() system call.

Is it possible to define a variable, in the source file of **prog** and it will be shared between the two instances of **prog**?

Comment: Yes it's possible to share variables between processes, search for *shared memory*. There are also other ways of [Inter-Process Communication (IPC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) that you could possibly use.

Comment: For a single variable, _memory mapping_ is the way to go.

Comment: Searching this site for `[c] shared data across processes` will bring up *dozens* of potentials.